# Removing titles from Orchard's Custom Form

Tags: forms, orchardcms

I have made a new from, but i want to remove the titles which are displayed before the input fields. I can't really understand how to edit placement.info file, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to have a look at this: [Alternates](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates)
Enable the Orchard Designer Tools Module, drill down to your Form and edit or change what you need.